# Configuring bootpd for a client with no hostname

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, bootp

I have a TI am335x which I am trying to get to network boot. I'm using bootpd on Ubuntu 14.04.

The BOOTP packet does not contain a "client hostname" (option 12?), so there's nothing I can specify for the *hostname* field. It does contain an option 60:

```
Message type: Boot Request (1)
Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
Hardware address length: 6
Hops: 0
Transaction ID: 0x00000001
Seconds elapsed: 0
Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
    0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
    .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
Client MAC address: TexasIns_12:c4:df (a0:f6:fd:12:c4:df)
Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
Server host name not given
Boot file name not given
Magic cookie: DHCP
Option: (60) Vendor class identifier
    Length: 10
    Vendor class identifier: AM335x ROM
Option: (61) Client identifier
    Length: 81
Option: (255) End
    Option End: 255
Padding
```

So in my bootptab, I've tried this:

```
"":T60="AM335x ROM":\
    :ht=1:\
    :td=/tftpboot:\
    :hd=/:\
    :bf=MLO:
```

And combinations, but it will not respond. I can confirm in the debug output of bootpd that it does see the request and ignores it.

How do I write a configuration entry for this boot request?